# Jenkins cant run my test properly,throws errors

Tags: java, jenkins, junit

I got a few simple tests,running under maven,locally its works fine,but when i tryed to run it on jenkins i got a error:
[image]

When i run test locally all works fine, i can find element,which jenkins think in no attached to document or clickable,i also use Explicitly Wait in order to wait for element to be clickable, really hope someone can help.
You can check my repo here https://github.com/KirillPochta/PageObjectTrue.git

Comment: Please don't post images, copy and paste the error message into your question.

Comment: From what I can see, you’re extensively relying on `Thread.sleep` to ensure the page is ready. This is _extremely_ fragile - and almost guaranteed to randomly fail. If you want stable Selenium tests you’re going to have to write better ones…

Comment: (Also, why do you have both JUnit and TestNG; using two testing frameworks is definitely a case of more is not better)

Comment: I recreated the project, carefully connected everything and everything worked, what was the error was unclear